# C: variable suddenly changes (why does that happen?)

Tags: c, variable-assignment

When I was toying around with some of the provided code from an online site, I have rather encountered a bizarre glitch I have never expected: a variable suddenly changes its value without any manual assignment.

here is the code below:

```
int rc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
printf("rc is equal to %d\n", rc); // should print out 1
if (rc != 1) die("Failed to write Database.");

rc = fflush(conn->file);
printf("rc is equal to %d\n", rc); // should print out 0
if (rc == -1); die("Cannot flush database"); // error handling
// error comes up because rc suddenly changes to -1
```

I do not understand how it happens, but like to know why a variable suddenly changes in C when it is not supposed to.

code source:
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych18.html
(Heap Stack and Memory under Database_write)

By the way, I am using vim in Terminal on Mac osx 10.6 snow leopard.

Comment: Note: If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, GCC will tell you exactly where your error is.  Clang will tell you by default.

Comment: Low hanging fruit draws ... maybe we can get another dozen answers mentioning the extra semi-colon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not change to -1. It is still zero.
You have a semicolon (;) in your code where you should not have it.
You should have instead:

```
if (rc == -1) die("Cannot flush database");
```

Comment: @JBRPG: I lost half of my hair because of these typoes I made myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

The value of `rc` doesn't change, rather there is a problem with your `if` statement:

```
if (rc == -1); die("Cannot flush database");
             ^
```

The second `if`-statement has no action associated with it. Unless the `;` is deleted, the `die()` will always be executed regardless of the value of `rc`. I.e., use this instead:

```
if (rc == -1) die("Cannot flush database");
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small error

```
 if (rc == -1);
              ^
              ^
```

so that the die statement is always executed. The value of the conditional is checked and never used

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bug:

```
if (rc == -1); die("Cannot flush database"); // error handling
```

Because of your `;` after the `if`, `die` is out of the scope of your `if`. This kind of bug is very possible and frequent if you are not writing structured code. This should have been:

```
if (rc == -1)
{
    die("Cannot flush database"); // error handling
}
```

If you have a `;` after the `if` in that, you will see that instantly.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, the semi-colon is your problem.

What you've done here, while not what you want, is perfectly legal -- it's called a null statement. This is written as a semi-colon and nothing else. The if statement, if true, is actually going ahead and executing a statement -- just a null one.